# Generate a random number with pre-defined length

Tags: php

with specific sequence like first 8 digits are current date 20160518{year-mm-dd] which always change and last 4 digits are random digit in php. I know how to generate random number using mt-rand() but how to manage sequence.
 I can generate random number using this code.

$randnum = rand(1111111111,9999999999);

but i want to restict first 8 digit like if someone place order on site then its format should be [yyyyddmm]and remaining number are random digits.
Output should be 201703158877.

Comment: _...how to manage sequence?..._ What do you mean by that? Show us your code and the expected output and tell us what does not work.

Comment: sidenote: is this db-related also?

Comment: ___Read your question back to yourself!___ But now pretend you dont know what you are talking about.. like us. Now ask yourself, could I answer this question with the information provided?

Comment: um.... combine them? no idea what you're really asking here; include an example output. (as already asked)

Comment: Let me have a guess what you want... your 12-digit sequence consists of the current date in the format yyyymmdd and 4 random numbers. You want to put those together and e.g. echo this or return them to work further with them. Am I right?

Comment: as per the edit: question's too broad.

Comment: and what does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: yes thats what i am asking

Comment: You can do this with like every language you want to. Just use google, it's one of the most basic things you could do.

Comment: @T.D Numbers like placing an order generate a table id. That ID is appended to a date string. Nothing "random" about that.

Comment: but i dont know how to implement it

Comment: @T.D use google!

Comment: okay so i get a idea how to do this.So thanks for helping me

Comment: Please review this post [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only 4 digits then give `rand()` a min and max that are only 4 digits long like this

```
$randnum = rand(1000,9999);
```

Then you will only get a 4 digit number back from the randomiser

Comment: *"then give mt_rand()"* - You meant *then give rand()...*, *n'est-ce pas true?*

Comment: Oui bien sur mon ami

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah my get out of Jail Free card `7.1.0 rand() has been made an alias of mt_rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

- mt_rand() function is used to generate random numbers in php.
- mt_rand() function is much faster then rand() function.
- **syntax:** mt_rand() or mt_rand($min , $max);
  **example of generate 4 digit random number in php**:

  [check Generate 4 Digit Unique Random Numbers](https://www.phpxpoint.com/how-can-i-generate-4-digit-unique-random-numbers-in-php/)